# Validate for Material UI Input without using Formik ValidationSchema

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I'm trying to add simple custom validation (non-empty or minimum characters) to a MUI TextField that is part of React functional component using the Formik useField hook. This reusable component will be a part of Formik form in it's parent component. The use of this functional child component is for it to be a reusable component and so the validation for the Textfield should occur within the component instead of the ValidationScheme attribute in the parent component's Formik tag since the form is not predefined. How can I add this custom validation to the TextField within the child component?

```
import React from 'react';
import { useField } from "formik";
import { TextField, TextFieldProps } from '@material-ui/core';


type FormikTextFieldProps = {
    formikKey: string,
} & TextFieldProps



const FormikTextField = ({ formikKey, ...props }: FormikTextFieldProps) => {
    const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(formikKey);

    const validate = () => {
        if(!field.value){
            helpers.setError('The field is empty')
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <>
            <TextField
                id={field.name}
                name={field.name}
                helperText={meta.touched ? meta.error : ""}
                error={meta.touched && Boolean(meta.error)}
                value={field.value}
                onChange={field.onChange}
                {...props}
            />
            {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
                <div className="error">{meta.error}</div>
            ) : null}
        </>
    )
}

export default FormikTextField
```